# Change UIStatusbarStyle even with UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar, uimodalpresentationstyle

I currently use `UIModalPresenationOverFullScreen` to present the next controller and at this moment I want to change the `UIStatusBarStyle`. The previous controller has got the `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` but in the current I want to use `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

Because of the `UIModalPresenationOverFullScreen` the previous controller is still alive in the background. Which causes the problem that the current will inherit that style.

In the plist file I've set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to YES and have been trying with some tips like:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle =UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle { 
      return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

Nothings seems to work. Anyone who'r run into the same problem. I still want the previous controller to be alive but change the `UIStatusBarstyle`.

Comment: use in viewdidLoad next controller  "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];"

Comment: Doesn't work. Same problem, still defaultstyle. @the1pawan

Answer (score 7):

You may use

```
self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = YES;
```

in the modal controller.

From the documentation:

> **modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance**  Property
>
> Specifies whether a view controller, presented non-fullscreen, takes over control of status bar appearance from the presenting view controller.